# How to trigger a click on a handsontable row/cell?

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I set up an afterOnCellMouseDown event and there are bunch of things I need to do after a cell is clicked.

I wanted to find out if there is a way to trigger a click event on a cell in handsontable?

I know there is a way to select a row or a column, but I specifically need to trigger a click event so that my afterOnCellMouseDown will be triggered.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure to understand. What event is going to trigger the click event ? Can you provide any example ?

Comment: This is a thread that I opened up on Github if its going to be useful in the future. https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/6822

Comment: @KBell - thanks for reaching out - this should be the demo of what I am trying to reach https://jsfiddle.net/vr29a1fh/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Piotr from the Handsontable team helped me out on this issue. 
He prepared the demo
Here is a link - https://jsfiddle.net/mfhqz69L/

You need to know that handsontable can't listen to click because the click is fired after a full click action occurs; that is, the mouse button is pressed and released while the pointer remains inside the same element. mousedown is fired the moment the button is initially pressed.
This is a link to full documentation - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event

```
var hot = new Handsontable(hotElement, hotSettings);

function triggerMouseEvent(type, target) {
  const event = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');

  event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 80, 20, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
  target.dispatchEvent(event);
}

var hotCell = hot.getCell(0, 0);

triggerMouseEvent('mousedown', hotCell);
```

Comment: I was testing a page using Selenium Webdriver - and had to be able to click on a handsontable row. The code above was half the solution: I needed to add a 'mouseup' event directly after the 'mousedown' to effectively perform a full click, as some javascript depending on the click event was never triggered otherwise.

Comment: this worked for me: `function triggerMouseEvent(type, target) { target.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("mousedown", { bubbles: true })) }` (note that `initMouseEvent` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/initMouseEvent))

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you are looking for but this is the way that I am doing it. It works very smooth for my needs.

```
afterOnCellMouseDown: function(event, coords) {
    if(coords.col == 18) // Column 18 of my table
    {
        let $id = hot.getDataAtCell(coords.row, 0); // row number and column number
        //console.log($id); // testing the results
        let $details = getOrderDetails($id); // function to pull in data to another section of the DOM
    } else {
       clearDetailInformation(); // functions to clear a few sections of the DOM
    } // end if
    hot.selectRows(coords.row); // puts a border around the clicked ROW
    } // end afterOnCellMouseDown
```